# Sharing records with roles based on recordtype and field value

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, criteria-based-sharing

My Org has 2 brands "A" and "B". On each contact record there is field called Brand. If this is populated with "A", record type is changed to "RT-A" and if Brand has value "B", record type is changed to "RT-B"

There are 2 profiles "case rep-A" and "case rep-B" who are assigned 'RT-A' and 'RT-B' recordtypes respectively from Sharing settings.

- OWD for contact to Private.
- Defined 2 criteria based sharing rules : 1) If brand on any record is A, share the record with Role and Subordinates of A 2) If brand on any record is B, share the record with Role and Subordinates of B

Now, created a contact with Brand = A as system admin and logged in as profile A but unable to view this contact.

Is there anything I am misssing.

Thanks

Comment: What role does the profile user has ?Note that sharing is defined based on roles and not on the profile

Comment: Forgot to mention..  Logged in as profile a which is. Under the main role for brand a.

Comment: Does profile has atleast read access to contact?

Comment: I just checked and yes the profiles has only read access to contacts

Comment: Can you share screenshots of your sharing rule and also make sure that record has proper record type changed by your process that assigns recordtype?

Comment: CaseRep-A profile has read access on contact but assigned recordtype is only RT-A which is also the default record type for this profile. In Sharing settings, defined a criteria based sharing rule which says if brand on contact is "A" change record type to "RT-A" and grant access to Role A and subordinates. The user I  logged in is under the role hierarchy of A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32561/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-pmvsdt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way which  can help in troubleshooting  and narrowing the problem

Query your contactShare table with newly created contactId and the userId for the user you are troubleshooting and if you dont get any records this means rule did not run.

```
[ Select ContactAccessLevel,
         ContactId,
         RowC‌​ause,
        UserOrGroupId 
       FROM ContactShare 
       WHERE ContactId='id' AND UserOrGroupId='userId'];
```

If you feel you are not missing its worth checking with SFDC support to see if they help you troubleshooting further